# Would upgrading the CMS solve the issue of JavaScript bug that prevents editing text?

Tags: javascript, bug

I have an ExpressionEngine website that has a bug in a JavaScript file that prevents text from being updated.  The bug manifests as text quickly erasing before it can be edited.  I discovered that I can disable JavaScript in my browser for page edits.  However, you can't do this permanently, as the CMS relies on JavaScript to function.  Would upgrading the CMS solve the issue?

Comment: Probably not - sounds like an add-on not is not behaving nicely. Have you tried disabling extensions?

Comment: Which fieldtype are you using for these text fields? What version of EE are you using?